# JavaCV - Identifying the most accurate of detected faces

Tags: javacv

I am new to the JavaCV/OpenCV thing, so apologies in advance if I'm being a complete idiot...

I need to detect the "primary/main" face in an image (This image will for the most part be a "Profile picture"), **face recognition** is not required.

Due to the fact that the different **haarcascade** files each detect different faces and that the faces detected are sometimes not actually faces but arbitrary artifacts in the image,  I need to decide which of the faces to use.
Assuming the faces detected are real faces, it makes sense to use the largest face because it is a profile pic.

The main problem I'm having is that the code detects (for some images) more that 1 face and the biggest face is actually not the persons face at all.
Here is an example from one of my tests where the code detected 2 faces, 1 being the real face and the other being the woman's bust, it just so happens that her bust is bigger than her face.

Face: `java.awt.Rectangle[x=62,y=42,width=78,height=78]` **Area of 6084**

Bust: `java.awt.Rectangle[x=86,y=144,width=80,height=80]` **Area of 6400**

[image]

So my question in short, if I have multiple detected faces, is there some sort of rating scale that I can use to determine which of the faces best matches what OpenCV sees as a face?

Comment: How are you doing the face detection? Options like `CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING` can actually help in cases like these, but there are other options to try as well...

Comment: _You know you're writing an awesome Stack Overflow question when it's on-topic and contains text "it just so happens that her bust is bigger than her face"_

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the face detection does not provide you such an option.
I guess your code looks something like this :

```
CvSeq faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(grayImage, cascade, ......);
```

So you get a CvSeq which is in fact nothing more than a pointer to the sequence of rectangles that delimits the faces. You get no more information about that.

Usually, I would say that the bust is under the head (even more, the head is above the rest of the body), except in some special cases ;).

You can simply utilize the Y position to discard the bust.

If other elements that are non body parts are detected as faces then you're doomed.